# Collapse table and remove padding in HTML

Tags: html

I am looking for a HTML attribute (not a CSS declaration) which will remove the padding from the `<table>` element. I would also like to achieve the same thing as is done with `border-collapse: collapse;`

I know that this can be very easily done with CSS by setting the `margin` and `border-collapse` properties of the table.

In my specific case, I am generating final documents with an old program which cannot read CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the classic attributes:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

that can control the cell padding, spacing and border?

Comment: I am looking for exactly this thank you! All answers I could find online were using pure CSS.